# read binary data using numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have a binary file and I wonder how I can read it using `numpy`. The format of the data is 10 characters of `string` followed by 100 `floats` (stored using 4 characters each). I know the following snippet with `struct` module can solve this, but for large files the struct code is too time-consuming.

```
f = open(file, 'rb')
while True:
    tag = f.read(10)
    if tag== '': break
    b = []
    for i in range(100):
      b.append(struct.unpack('f', f.read(4)))
    yield tag, b
```

I'm a little confused with the `numpy.fromfile`, it seems this can meet my requirement.

Comment: a sample of your input? the first few lines atleast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fromfile` takes an open file object.  Without a test file, I'll just write some code without testing it:

```
f = open('test', 'rb')
arr1 = np.fromfile(f, dtype='S1', count=10)
arr2 = np.fromfile(f, dtype='f4')  # count=100 optional
f.close()
```

In words - open the file, read the string part, then read the float part.

If it's a repeated pattern, it should work to put that code in a loop.  I'd then collect the `arg1` and `arg2` pieces in lists, and concatenate at the end.